# How to use parameter from Firebase Dynamic Link as Flutter Named Route parameter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, routes, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a route called "/song", which takes parameters. And this is how I access within the app:
`() => Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/song", arguments: "my_id");`

How can I convert URL params to in-app route arguments?

Example:
When I open `https://myapp.page.link/song&id=some_id`, it opens `/song` route with `"some_id"` argument.

NOTE: Data is dynamically loaded on both website and app, therefore it's very impractical to implement deep link for each one of them manually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - How to pass custom arguments in firebase dynamic links for app invite feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58481840/flutter-how-to-pass-custom-arguments-in-firebase-dynamic-links-for-app-invite)