# Flutter Dynamic linking not available for web apps?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

**My Use Case:**

Users in my app can create lists of items. I want the users to be able to share a link to one of their lists.

I want individuals who click the shared link to see the list of items in a web browser and not need the app installed.

**Create the Dynamic Link**

The first thing I need to do is create a dynamic link for a user to share. I struggled with this at first and then looked at this question here: [Flutter - How to pass custom arguments in firebase dynamic links for app invite feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58481840/flutter-how-to-pass-custom-arguments-in-firebase-dynamic-links-for-app-invite)

After looking at that I build my own class like so:

```
class PackDynamicLinkService {
  Future<Uri> createDynamicLink({required String packID}) async {
    final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      // This should match firebase but without the username query param
      uriPrefix: 'ttps://appName.app/p',
      // This can be whatever you want for the uri, https://yourapp.com/groupinvite?username=$userName
      link: Uri.parse('https://appName.app/p?pack=$packID'),
      androidParameters: const AndroidParameters(
        packageName: 'com.test.demo',
        minimumVersion: 1,
      ),
      iosParameters: const IOSParameters(
        bundleId: 'com.test.demo',
        minimumVersion: '1',
        appStoreId: '',
      ),
    );

    final dynamicLink = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildShortLink(
      parameters,
      shortLinkType: ShortDynamicLinkType.unguessable,
    );
    return dynamicLink.shortUrl;
  }
}
```

I then called that function in my app and I am able to get a URL that looks like this: `https://appName.app/p?pack=lVeSBUHoLX52zPqAiB9A`

So far so good. Now I just need to click the link and read the parameter `$packID` that I passed to it inside my web app. Then I can route them to the correct view and display the list.

**Processing Dynamic Link**

in my marin.dart I tried to retrieve the params with:

```
//get link stuff
  final PendingDynamicLinkData? initialLink =
      await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
  if (initialLink != null) {
    final Uri fullLink = initialLink.link;
    print(fullLink.queryParameters['pack']);
  }
```

but when I upload to firebase hosting to see if this code works for testing, I get this error:

> Uncaught MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method
> FirebaseDynamicLinks#getInitialLink on channel
> plugins.flutter.io/firebase_dynamic_links)

After doing some more research it seems that firebase_dynamic_links package may not be available for web? So does that mean my original use case is not possible with flutter at this time?

Answer (score -1):

You would want to take the link received and parse it using something like:

```dart
var PendingDynamicLinkData? initialLink =
      await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();

if (kIsWeb) {
  String link = Uri.base;

  initialLink = await 
  FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getDynamicLink(Uri.parse(link));
}

if (initialLink != null) {
  final Uri fullLink = initialLink.link;
  print(fullLink.queryParameters['pack']);
}
```

Here, we are checking if its a web app and then we can parse the dynamic link and get the info for it. We just check for the Uri that was used in our web app.

Comment: what does this line do, if you are resetting initialLink a few lines later:

var PendingDynamicLinkData? initialLink =
      await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();

Comment: Also I dont think this solves my original problem that package:firebase_dynamic_links is not available for web. This would still crash on web no?  SInce that package isnt available for web?

Comment: The if (kIsWeb) checks that the app is running in a browser and then handles the dynamic link. Ahh I did not realize that the package was not available on the web

Comment: firebase dynamic link won't support to  flutter web